# UI Dialog modal windows work as modal window on the second click

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, dialog, window, modal-dialog

I have problem with Jquery UI dialog,when i click the button the first time, it does show the dialog but not in modal dialog, but when  you click it the second time, it show it correctly as a modal dialog

```
$('.ajax').live('click', function ()
{
    var url = "/home/test";
    var dialog = $("#dialog");

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        title:"Title",
        modal: true
    });


    if ($("#dialog").length == 0)
    {
        dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
    }
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings)
            {
                //show an animated gif
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus)
            {
                //hide the animated gif
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                dialog.dialog().html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                dialog.dialog().html("An error occured...");
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Here is the code for the button click event

```
<button class="ajax">open dialog</button>
```

see this link to test the above code

http://jsfiddle.net/jRPfu/13/

Comment: Please you can see the functional code here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jRPfu/13/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

1. You declare a variable `dialog` so use it afterwards
2. Check directly if a #dialog element was found with `dialog.length`. In case it's empty, create your markup
3. Initialize your dialog with the option `autoOpen: false`. This way the dialog is initialized once and for all but it will remain hidden.
4. In your ajax callbacks, call the open method to show the dialog with `dialog.dialog('open')`. As a side note, it seems more logic to set the content of the dialog and then open it.

Further reading:

- [autoOpen option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-autoOpen)
- [open method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-open)

Here's the modified code:

```
var dialog = $("#dialog");

if (dialog.length == 0) {

    dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');

    dialog.dialog({
        height: 140,
        title: "Title",
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });

}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        dialog.html(data).dialog('open');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        dialog.html("An error occured...").dialog('open');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ffFG6/)**